# Javascript/ IE Date time error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

With this code in IE:

```
if(!Date.prototype.toISOString) Date.prototype.toISOString = function(){
    var padZero = function(str, len){while(str.length < len) str = '0' + str; return str;};

    var ret = padZero(''+this.getUTCFullYear(), 4)
        + '-' + padZero(''+this.getUTCMonth(), 2)
        + '-' + padZero(''+this.getUTCDate(), 2)
        + 'T' + padZero(''+this.getUTCHours(), 2)
        + ':' + padZero(''+this.getUTCMinutes(), 2)
        + ':' + padZero(''+this.getUTCSeconds(), 2)
        + 'Z';
    alert(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

I get the following error..

An error occurred while executing the urlrewrite query: err:FORG0001: illegal lexical form for date-time-like value '2012-00-05T09:09:46Z' Invalid value 0 for Month field. [at line 42, column 9]

I have tried several fixes to the month parameter but can't seem to get it right..So, any help would be greatly appricated.

BTW: They code above works fine in Firefox..Go figure, right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getUTCMonth()` is zero based, so `0` is January. You could add 1 to it to form your date string:

```
+ '-' + padZero(''+(this.getUTCMonth()+1), 2)
```

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> getUTCMonth - Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to universal time.

Comment: That worked and so simple. Doof!! Its official, I am an idiot!haha